# Why didn't Tom Riddle kill Harry in Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-chamber-of-secrets

I remember from 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets' that in the climax, Harry was shocked after finding Ginny Weasley on floor and **drops the wand** which is then picked up by Tom Riddle (his memory).

Also we saw that he commanded the Basilisk to attack Harry.

So why couldn't he just kill him with a curse by wand?

Comment: Probably for the same reason Bond villains always put him in some faulty [death trap](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathTrap)\torture device instead of just putting a bullet in his head.

Comment: @Walt: I see your point. But am sure there might be some reason. Maybe in the book.

Comment: Well, Tom knows the Killing Curse didn't work on Harry once. So he might be a bit wary of trying it while he's still weak and not fully formed yet. Maybe he can barely perform magic at all at this state other than jumble shiny letters around.

Comment: @Walt: That is indeed one good point.

Comment: @Walt, if Diary is a memory of the past of Voldemort(which earlier was Tom Riddle) then how come a memory know about what happened after that. I mean Voldemort tried to kill baby Harry potter in Godric's Hollow and this happened after a huge time gap from the memory's time?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## In-Universe Reasons

- Riddle is not fully formed yet. He's a memory *almost* made flesh, so he can grab Harry's wand and even create some shiny letters with it, but it's possible that's the extent of his powers.
- Riddle also knows that the Killing Curse didn't work on Harry once and rebounded on Voldemort, so he might be wary of trying this powerful spell again on Harry, especially in his state.
- Riddle wants to humiliate Harry first, to show him that his powers are no match to his. As he says:

> So this is what Dumbledore sends his great defender. A songbird and an old hat. Let's match the power of Lord Voldemort, Heir of Salazar Slytherin, against the famous Harry Potter.

And in the book, this is preceded by:

> I’m going to teach you a little lesson.

Just like in the graveyard duel in *Goblet of Fire*, Riddle\Voldemort favors a spectacle, a feat of strength, to show Harry that he's not the great  Gryffindor hero everyone says he is. Because...

## Out of Universe Reason

...Voldemort is the very epitome of a supervillain, and as such, is prone to [gloating](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilGloating), monologuing, explaining his evil plan to the hero and then putting him in some [death trap](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathTrap) that always fails to work. When you simply kill the hero, you are just a killer... But when you mock him first and plan his demise in some fiendishly clever way, you're truly a *villain*. ;)

Comment: Aaaand I see there was a [similar question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55128/why-didnt-tom-riddle-kill-harry-potter-in-chamber-of-secrets) on SF&F... But *of course*. ;)

Comment: @Walt: I didn't knew there are two communities for Movies. I found this one first in *All Communities* section. Good answer. Given that one is already present your points have uniqueness.

Comment: @Rahul Sci-fi & Fantasy Stack Exchange isn't just for movies; it's for books and other media as well. Thus it covers a lot of works that would not be appropriate here. The overlap is when there are questions about sci-fi or fantasy movies. In that case, just ask on whichever site you would like.

Comment: I feel that this answer would be improved by adding this link to the final *villain*: https://youtu.be/dy2zB8bLSpk?t=28